# Problema con Firebase Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-messaging

Tengo un problema a la hora de crear una aplicación Android con Firebase.
Tengo creado una aplicacion de mensajes, en la cual, el usuario se registra o inicia sesión.
En Firestore tiene creada una coleccion "users" en la cual guardo información del usuario, y otra de "chats" en la cual, guarda el Uid del usuario y el mensaje que envía:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la parte en la que recibe el mensaje y lo sube a Firestore, pero no se como realizarlo para que despues lea esa coleccion, saque el mensaje y lo ponga en el Listview.

```
private void displayChatMessages() {
    ListView listOfMessages = findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);



    FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
            .setLayout(R.layout.message)
            .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("chats").child("mensaje"),ChatMessage.class)
            .build();


    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            // Get references to the views of message.xml
            TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageUser = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            // Set their text
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

            // Format the date before showing it
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                    model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };

    listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y coloca tu código como texto. Revisa [Cómo hacer una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [haz el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer mejor como funciona el sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder obtener los mensajes de un usuario en especifico de la coleccion chats deberias hacer una query incluyendo al usuario para solo traer esos mensajes

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("chats").whereEqualTo("usuario",userID).get().addOnCompleteListener...
```

Con esta query solo vas a obtener los chats del userID que mandes en la query, si el userID es el usuario que actualmente esta usando la app puedes usar `getCurrentUser().getUid()`